# nuget source code transformations escape character

Tags: nuget, transformation, nuspec

I am creating a nuget package which constains a `sample.nuspec.pp` file itself.

Now I want to write i.e. `$version$` literaly but (obviously) after installing the package it gets replaced with `1.0.0.0`.

This is my `Sample.nuspec.pp`. How do I escape the `$propertyName$` entries properly?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>$version$</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <owners>$author$</owners>
    <licenseUrl>...</licenseUrl>
    <projectUrl>...</projectUrl>
    <iconUrl>...</iconUrl>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>$description$</description>
    <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
    <copyright>Copyright 2019</copyright>
    <tags></tags>
    <releaseNotes></releaseNotes>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/nuget/reference/nuspec#replacement-tokens) specify that tokens can come from project file or you can use the `-properties` switch of `pack` command

So in your project file you can add :

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PackageOutputPath Condition="$(PackageOutputPath) == ''">$(OutputPath)/PackageOutputPath>
    <Title>MyTitle</Title>
    <Version>1.0.0</Version>
    <Authors>Me</Authors>
    <Description>My library</Description>
    <Copyright>Copyright © 2019</Copyright>
    <IncludeSymbols>true</IncludeSymbols>
</PropertyGroup>
```

**Edit**

After a new read of your question, i think i misunderstand it:

You can try escape with `$$propertyName$$`